# Probability of life expectancy

Tags: probability

I've been having problems with this question. I think I have an idea of what I have to do but I can't get the final answer.

> Let's say the probability of a person to live to at least 70 years old is 4/5 and the probability to live to at least 80 years old is 1/2.
>
> Let's say this person, Jason, just celebrated his 70th birthday. What is the probability that Jason will live to 80 years old?

I'm thinking:

> Let A=celebrating 70th birthday and let B=celebrating 80th birthday.
> Pr(A)=4/5 and Pr(B)=1/2. So, Pr(B|A) = Pr(B and A)/Pr(A)

Comment: That is correct. And $\Pr(B\cap A)=\Pr(B)$, so we get $\frac{1/2}{4/5}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(B|A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$$.

Where A is the event of person living to 70, and B is the event of person living to 80. It is absurd to say that B can occur without A occurring, because if the person lives to 80, he *must've* crossed 70. So $P(A \cap B) = P(B)$. Therefore this reduces to:

$$P(B|A) = \frac{1/2}{4/5} = \frac54*\frac12 = \frac58$$